# How to pass options to a LaTeX font in R Markdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

`rmarkdown`, following {xe|lua}latex, allows to specify fonts for main text, sans-serif text, monspaced text (most notably code chunks !) and math fonts in the YAML header. At least for PDF rendering via xetex, this works.

However, I found no (documented) way to pass options to the underlying `setxxxfont` \LaTeX command. For example, the YAML fragment :

````
```
monofont: Inconsolata
```
````

generates the following \LaTeX fragment :

```
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-ansi]{Inconsolata}
```

I have two questions with this:

1. why is the `Mapping=tex-ansi` added ? And how to control it ? (I'm working in UTF8...).
2. How could I set additional arguments for the font options i.e. `\setmonofont[Scale=0.91]{TeX Gyre Cursor}`?

The R Markdown [book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/) and the Pandoc's User's [Guide](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) did not reveal anything pertinent.

Comment: Hope the answer helps. As a tip, try and keep StackOverflow question to one distinct problem at a time as [described well here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/387544).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Background:**

When R Markdown converts the knitted code to the output format (PDF), a pandoc template is used. The template is stored [within the package](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex), and any variables which get replaced by the YAML variables are contained in the `$$` Notation

**1. Encoding**

The `Mapping=tex-ansi`  is added to the code as a workaround an issue as reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/889). Therefore I would be cautious of deleting this for potential side effects.

If you do indeed wish to change this code, you will have to make a copy of the LaTeX template file used to convert the document. You can find the default template [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex). See here for some more information on providing [custom templates](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format#custom_templates).

**2. Additional Font Options**

You can use the `monofontoptions` YAML argument to add additional arguments to the font options.

> Documentation of the variables which can be parsed by the LaTeX output are available in the [pandoc documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `monofontoptions` option is not documented. Did you discover it by reading the source ?

Comment: I have updated the answer to provide a link to the documentation.

Comment: thank you very much ! I read the damn thing 'til I grew blue, and still missed it... An HTML page is no replacement for a real, organized manual (do you hear me, `knitr` ? Do you hear me, `rmarkdown` ?)... Yihui Xie's books are a large step in the right direction but still miss a good index.

Comment: BTW : One could think that authors would jump at the HTML (yes, "Hypertext" !) format to create interactive indexes (indices ?), but no. The only [reference](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/latex-index.html) I found(in `bookdown's book), states :

"Currently the index is only supported for LaTeX/PDF output."

Speak about lost opportunities...

Comment: Rmarkdown is based on a complex interactions of multiple different bits of software (rmarkdown/knitr/pandoc/LaTeX). This issue very much is pandoc related, so it is difficult to fault knitr for not providing the documentation on all the options. But I agree that it could be clearer on what options could be set.